# validation not working on formArray with multiple controls

Tags: angular, validation, formarray

[image]I am working on mat-chip-list which has formArray control declared for input.

**Current Behavior:**
When I simply submit the form Without filling any form fields the mat-chip-list doesn't have any formcontrols inside it but when I print the formGroup the required:true validation showing but the red border for mat-chio-list box is not showing.

**Expected Behavior:**
form validation has to show for mat-chip-list with red border

**My Component.ts:**

```
this.composeMailForm = new FormGroup({
  to_emails: new FormArray([], Validators.required),
  cc_emails: new FormControl(),
  bcc_emails: new FormControl(),
  from_email: new FormControl(),
  subject: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
  body: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
});

onSubmit(){
  console.log("form controls after submit",this.composeMailForm);
  if(this.composeMailForm.valid){
   ------------
   ------------
  }else{
    this.composeMailForm.controls.body.markAsTouched();
    const ctrls = this.composeMailForm.get('to_emails') as FormArray;
    ctrls.markAsTouched();
    ctrls.controls.forEach(control => control.markAsTouched());
    this.composeMailForm.controls.subject.markAsTouched();
  }

add(event: MatChipInputEvent, email_type): void {
  const input = event.input;
  const value = event.value;
  if ((value || '').trim()) {
    if(email_type === 'to_email'){
      const to_emails = this.composeMailForm.get('to_emails') as FormArray;
      to_emails.push(this.fb.control(value.trim()));
    }
  }
}

remove(index: number, email_type): void {
  if(email_type === 'to_email'){
    const to_emails = this.composeMailForm.get('to_emails') as FormArray;
    if (index >= 0) {
      to_emails.removeAt(index);
    }
  }
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<mat-label>To</mat-label>
<mat-chip-list #chipList ngDefaultControl formArrayName="to_emails" >
  <mat-chip *ngFor="let email of composeMailForm.get('to_emails').controls; let i = index;" [selectable]="selectable" [removable]="removable"
                      (removed)="remove(i,'to_email')" ngDefaultControl >
 {{email.value}}
   <mat-icon matChipRemove *ngIf="removable">cancel</mat-icon>
  </mat-chip>
  <input [matChipInputFor]="chipList" [matChipInputSeparatorKeyCodes]="separatorKeysCodes"
                      [matChipInputAddOnBlur]="addOnBlur" (matChipInputTokenEnd)="add($event,'to_email')" >
</mat-chip-list>
```

How to achieve this, Any Idea? Thanks.

Comment: Stackblitz example?

Comment: I am new to stackblitz, I am unable to create stackblitz example.

Comment: Can you show the full TS code? `fb`? and add your code in [Stackblitz here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-y6jyau)

Comment: I have added ts code there, please check it once.

Comment: Unable to find the code